# Adding and removing items in Chrome App

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-app

I want to develop a Chrome app that can store items, if I add a photo it will add up as new item in a list. What I am trying to achieve here is some sort of photo gallery. It will then be stored in Chrome's local storage and maybe synced up (not sure about the syncing part yet).

I have finished the design, I just need to know how to execute this. I am not asking for code, I just want leads on where I can do this. Examples or articles. Maybe a specific framework or anything can help me with this? This would be easier if done in PHP but Chrome app doesn't support this.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome's [sync filesystem](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/syncFileSystem.html) seems most appropriate for storing and syncing photos.